# Inheriting from one baseclass that implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged, radix

I have this BaseClass:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and a other class:

```
public class SchemaDifferenceViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string firstSchemaToCompare;

    public string FirstSchemaToCompare
    {
        get { return firstSchemaToCompare; }
        set
        {
            firstSchemaToCompare = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstSchemaToCompare"));
                //StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

PropertyChanged is here ( 2Times ), red underlined, it says:

```
Error   1   The event BaseViewModel.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'SchemaDifferenceFinder.ViewModel.BaseViewModel')
```

What I'm doing wrong? I only swept the PropertyChangedEvent to a new class: BaseViewModel..

Comment: Link moved again: http://george.softumus.com/inotifypropertychanged-and-magic-strings/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *cannot* raise the event outside the class it is declared in, use the method in the base class to raise it (make `OnPropertyChanged` `protected`).

Comment: @eMi: I said you should use the method, making it `protected` is just the necessary step to do so. Do not try to raise the event.

Answer (score 3):

Change derived class as follow:

```
public class SchemaDifferenceViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string firstSchemaToCompare;

    public string FirstSchemaToCompare
    {
        get { return firstSchemaToCompare; }
        set
        {
            firstSchemaToCompare = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstSchemaToCompare");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a base class for INPC is bad design in my opinion.

This is the textbook place where you could use a [mixin](http://remix.codeplex.com/)

In short, it allows you to provide a default implementation of an interface's members. You would still be able to inherit from an actually interesting class =)